# How to search Amazon for 5-star-rated products with at least 10 ratings?

Tags: amazonsellercentral

Oftentimes, when searching products on Amazon, I want to see the products with the best ratings.  More often than not, when sorting by Customer Ratings, Amazon will display products that have a 5-star rating from just one rating, which is not enough of a sample size to tell me much about those products.

So how can I search Amazon for 5-star-rated products that have received a minimum of `X` ratings (e.g. 10) and only *then* sort by ratings?

Can this only be done via their API or can this be done on their website directly via some kind of advanced search?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with the API - Amazon removed star ratings (and review count) from it back in 2010, and the API now only shows them as part of a block of reviews in an iframe. So the only way to extract this information is to scrape Amazon - either the site itself, or inside those frames - which of course they do not take kindly to!

Answer (score 0):

You type in “5 star rated…” and then whatever it is you’re looking for. It will show you the 5 star rated items. I’m not sure if it will show you all of them but this has worked pretty well for me.